# JSON - Unity: How can I serialize a list? NullReferenceException error

Tags: json, list, unity-game-engine

Here is the code I've been trying to use to serialize a list into JSON:

```
void Save()
        {
            Debug.Log("Save");

            InfoSaveList saveList = new InfoSaveList();

            // this steps through information nodes and collects 
            // the information they contain
            foreach (BaseNode n in rootNode.childrenNodes)
            {
                var id = n.nodeID;
                var info = n.infoLine;

                InfoSave infoSaveData = new InfoSave();
                infoSaveData.nodeID = id;
                infoSaveData.info = info;

                saveList.infoSave.Add(infoSaveData);

            }
            string infoSaveDataToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveList, true);
            Debug.Log(infoSaveDataToJson);
        }


[System.Serializable]
public class InfoSave
{
    public int nodeID;
    public string info;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class InfoSaveList
{

    [SerializeField] public List<InfoSave> infoSave;
}
```

for some reason I'm getting the error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

on the line:

```
saveList.infoSave.Add(infoSaveData);
```

I can't figure out why that would be the case, I'm trying to step through my code and it all seems to make sense to me but I'm clearly missing something.

If i get through this error, will this even save correctly as JSON? or can that only be done with arrays no lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply never instantiate your list.

Either do it through a constructor, when declaring the list, or from your Save function since the list is public.

```
// Constructor :

[System.Serializable]
public class InfoSaveList
{

    [SerializeField] public List<InfoSave> infoSave;

    public InfoSaveList()
    {
         infoSave = new List<InfoSave>();
    }
}
```

---

```
// Declaration :

[System.Serializable]
public class InfoSaveList
{

    [SerializeField] public List<InfoSave> infoSave = new List<InfoSave>();
}
```

---

```
// From Save function

void Save()
{
    // ...
    InfoSaveList saveList = new InfoSaveList();
    saveList.infoSave = new List<InfoSave>();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm so dumb, this was it! Thanks!